# How do I upgrade Tkinter 8.6.8 to 8.6.9?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying unsuccessfully for the past few hours to upgrade tkinter 8.6.8 to 8.6.9. (or 8.6.10)

I'm doing this because I'm trying to compile a tkinter app with cx_freeze and it only shows a black screen. I've been told upgrading to this version will work.

The problem is, I don't know where to put the files or where to get the files for the new version.

If anybody could point me to this information, that would be great.

I am running macOS Catalina and Python 3.9.

Comment: @BryanOakley you are right. I removed my comment. Usually tkinter comes with the core version of the Python. Maybe OP can share some system information as OS, Python (framework). I vastly remember that you can install/update tcl with `apt-get install tcl`?

Comment: Tell us what OS you are using, what python version, and how you are trying to "compile" your program.

Comment: I am using macOS Catalina and compiling with cx_Freeze.

Comment: I am also using Python 3.9

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, and it was quite simple to fix. I know this seems kind of basic, but if you uninstall then reinstall Tkinter, pip should automatically update Tkinter to the latest version.

These are the commands to do this:

```
pip uninstall tkinter
```

&

```
pip install tkinter
```

Also, if for some reason pip isn't working (this also happened to me), just use this:

```
python (or py) -m pip install tkinter
```

Comment: You can do that in a single command using pip's `--upgrade` option.

Comment: `tkinter` cannot be installed using `pip`.